# Inform users of certain tags on the existence of a new SE-2.0 site and offer to automatically post the question there instead

Tags: feature-request, tags, migration, stackexchange-2.0

Take for example [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) both at SO and SU. Now that there's http://tex.stackexchange.com, (new) users asking a LaTeX question should at least be informed that there is a new Stack Exchange site dedicated to TeX and thus increases their chance of an answer. This should happen before the question is actually posted and ideally offer the option to post the question directly there instead (without the need to copy-paste).

LaTeX is just an example, there's also [physics](/questions/tagged/physics), [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu), [gamedev](/questions/tagged/gamedev) etc., and it is obvious that this can only be decided on a case-by-case basis which is why I certainly do *not* suggest migrating questions automatically when these tags are used. But informing users of that possibility would probably help the SE network in general.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12570/this-question-may-belong-to-another-site-consider-migrating-feature-request

Comment: @marcog: thanks&upvoted. therefore also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18795/146482

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see this as being advantageous in the majority of scenarios that will turn up. It's mostly because the relationship between different sites is a lot more complex than the binary yes/no from the presence or absence of a particular tag.

In an ideal scenario, the availability of a tag on a site indicates that *the topic of questions is acceptable to that site*. For example, there's an Ubuntu tag on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) because you can ask about Ubuntu on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). It's not as if Ubuntu experts only hang out in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/). This kind of cross-applicability of scope between two or more sites is where the majority of these kinds of tags will show up. One could ask on a specialized site, but if they don't want to it'll just be pestersome to have to deal with this suggestion every time.

There's also the point that a question that gets a particular tag on one site *might be inappropriate for the specialized site*. badp brings up the Android tag, which is an excellent example of this. Android development is off-topic for the [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/). More likely than not, someone using the Android tag on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) will be asking a question that does not belong on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

This leaves the scenario where the question doesn't belong on the current site, but does belong on a different site. In the majority of these scenarios, *the tag shouldn't even exist at all to use*, and that's why migration paths don't exist in the majority of cases. For example, one won't expect to find [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) questions on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), so having a Physics tag to redirect isn't very useful.

To top it all off, for all 3 scenarios I point out, the scope of the tag isn't necessary congruent with the scope of the site. Take the Apple tag on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). It can be asking about Apple software and hardware, which are on-topic. But it could be asking about Apple devices like the iPad, which are off-topic.

---

I don't oppose the less-obnoxious methods that [badp suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82140/inform-users-of-certain-tags-on-the-existence-of-a-new-se-2-0-site-and-offer-to-a/82150#82150). But as far as where a question belongs, existing tags are [not always the best indicator of this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags).

Comment: +1 that's why I said "it is obvious that this can only be decided on a case-by-case basis". Although, if you take [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2580933/321973) SO question slightly more server focused and migrate it to SF, a physics tag wouldn't be _too_ inappropriate... But as I mentioned, I'm only asking for a "Did you know there's a site specifically for `android` questions when they are _not_ about development?" kind message when a tag indicates _potential_ (but not unfailingly valid) interestingness, not an automated migration

Comment: @Tobias Your example is something that seems very annoying to see when someone wants to ask more than one Android development question on Stack Overflow. I know you said case-by-case basis, that's why I wrote this answer - I'm saying that there's far too few cases where that's a net positive result. In most cases it isn't necessary to suggest, the suggestion may not even apply to the question they're asking, or they won't have the tag to use.

Answer (score 3):

I think the least obnoxious way this could be done is through:

1. Tag wiki excerpts, which are shown when you hover a tag (and *you* can make this happen!), and
2. Tag ads (like for [android](/questions/tagged/android), although that *is* going to devalue that 'ad placement' position).

Comment: I think the problem with 1. is that new users probably don't know about hovering and since the tags are by design selected _after_ writing the question body some might simply think "nah, I won't copy paste that to another site..." But +1 for 2.

Comment: @Tobias eh, you don't have to be a new user to be oblivious to the 40-some SEs currently active

Comment: 60-some already?! that makes it even more important to raise the public awareness

Comment: @Tobias 46 exactly right now (whoops!)

Comment: still enough, I think I couldn't name more than ~15 without looking or making some up