# Automatically suggest asking on another site

Tags: feature-request, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [This question may belong to <Another site>, consider migrating - feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12570/this-question-may-belong-to-another-site-consider-migrating-feature-request)

We all know how common it is for someone to ask a question better suited to one of the other SE sites. Some are more obvious than others and can be automatically detected. For example, any question with the [latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex) tag is very likely better suited on https://tex.stackexchange.com/. When a user hits submit, he could be offered to post this on the other site instead. Very often users just aren't aware of these other sites, so a suggestion could do the trick.