# How to get new (not algorithm/macro specific) TeX/LaTeX questions to tex.SE rather than SO?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [This question may belong to <Another site>, consider migrating - feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12570/this-question-may-belong-to-another-site-consider-migrating-feature-request)

The Tex.SE site has been up for a while, and I agree that it's not wise to move tons of dead questions from Stack Overflow to it. But what about new questions? When looking at the newest questions with the [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) tag, most have no algorithmic background and thus would be better asked on Tex.SE.

So how do we get these questions asked there? Would it help to have a popup message (like the one shown when you downvote) mentioning that one could get better answers by asking the question on Tex.SE when the [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) tag is used?

Comment: Suggesting an edit to the tag wiki excerpt that mentions the TeX.SE site would be a good start. At least some conscientious question-askers would notice that. (Although remember, [the consensus is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stack-overflow) that TeX/LaTeX questions are generally on-topic for SO.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [This question may belong to <Another site>, consider migrating - feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12570/this-question-may-belong-to-another-site-consider-migrating-feature-request), [Automatically suggest asking on another site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73032/automatically-suggest-asking-on-another-site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my thoughts/ideas related to this request.

1. May be a new attribute (say *`relatedStackExchange`*) can be added to tags, not visible to all users (probably just diamond moderators). These attributes will define the website where the tag may be more suitable. For example: [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) tag will have the value https://tex.stackexchange.com/ in the new attribute *`relatedStackExchange`*.
2. When a user tags a question under [latex](/questions/tagged/latex) on Stack Overflow website, the site can check if the tag used on the question has a value in the attribute *`relatedStackExchange`*, If it does, then the message shown below can be displayed.
3. If we want to go one step further, the user can click on the box and the question can be transferred to the Ask Question page of the respective site (let's say https://tex.stackexchange.com/ in this case).

I am not sure how much work is involved in this but I hope this might save time in closing and migrating questions that don't belong on SO but may be relevant on other web sites.

As @Cody pointed out, it seems that the consensus is that latex questions are allowed on SO but I do see quite a few questions migrated from the tag [latex](/questions/tagged/latex).

[image: Suggestion]

Comment: seems to me you could just put this in the tag wiki excerpt, like so ... http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/rename-or-remove-old-games/2531#2531