# Should the User-Experience tag wiki suggest asking a question on UX.SE instead?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, site-crossover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [This question may belong to <Another site>, consider migrating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12570/this-question-may-belong-to-another-site-consider-migrating)
>   [Automatically suggest asking on another site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73032/automatically-suggest-asking-on-another-site)

The [user-experience](/questions/tagged/user-experience) tag seems to often exist on questions that belong on UX.Stack Exchange. But the tag wiki doesn't do a great job of *telling* the user that their UX questions are most likely better asked on UX.SE.

Here's the current tag wiki text:

> (see also ux.stackexchange.com) the experiential, affective, meaningful and valuable aspects of human-computer interaction and product ownership, but also a person’s perceptions of the practical aspects such as utility, ease of use and efficiency of the system. Essentially, it's about how a person feels about using a product.

The current tag wiki suggests "(see also ux.stackexchange.com)" but doesn't actually call the user to take action. It should at least indicate that UX.SE is a site *for* UX questions, if not outright state "*your question probably belongs on UX.SE instead*".

Do we have any other tag wikis which nudge askers to ask on a different site? Unlike Database questions, which might belong here or on DBA or both, most UX questions I see on SO are either solidly UX (what should I do) or solidly programming (how do I do this).

Comment: @MichaelMrozek that's a (recursive dupe of) suggestion to auto suggest migrations. I support that too, but IMO this is an issue that should be addressed via the user-experience tag wiki as well, as the tag wiki is supposed to give guidance on how a tag should be used.