# Suggest to post directly on the matching specialized stackexchange site when specific tags are used

Tags: feature-request, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [This question may belong to <Another site>, consider migrating - feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12570/this-question-may-belong-to-another-site-consider-migrating-feature-request)

For *example*, the StackExchange site "Drupal Answers" is going in beta soon, and there are many questions tagged `drupal`, `drupal-6` and `drupal-7` on StackOverflow.

Wouldn't it make sense, when a user is about to post a message with one of these tags on Stackoverflow, to have the form suggest that the question may better fit "Drupal Answers" instead ?

(And if you want to go crazy, you could even add a second "submit" button for posting directly on the other site instead of SO :-)

---

I think that would help new users get to know the other SE sites and would reduce the number of questions that need review to be migrated from SO.