# Provide option to migrate when asking a question

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [This question may belong to <Another site>, consider migrating - feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12570/this-question-may-belong-to-another-site-consider-migrating-feature-request)

Often when a question that is clearly a better fit for a different SE site is asked on SO, there are a slew of comments suggesting that the OP post it at xxx.SE or people vote to migrate or a moderator migrates it. All of these take time, and sometimes on tags with less traffic, it can take longer.

Instead, why don't we offer an option to the OP to post on a sister site when they are composing the question? For e.g., if someone writes a question and tags it [latex](/questions/tagged/latex), then when they hit submit, a pop-up can ask them:

> There is a site dedicated for T<sub>E</sub>X and L<sup>A</sup>T<sub>E</sub>X questions, where you might have a better chance of getting a quick answer. Would you like to ask this question there instead? <kbd>Yes</kbd>     <kbd>No</kbd>

This detection will be based on tags on SO from where questions are frequently migrated. Clicking on **Yes** will take them to a compose screen on the second site where they can choose the tags and submit (this is necessary so that they choose the right tag. e.g. [unix](/questions/tagged/unix) on unix.SE is redundant). That way, the OP is made aware of the existence of such a site and can ask their question at the right site the first time. Worst case, they ask on SO and we migrate it as we do now.

Users familiar with SO and who know that their question is a better fit for SO (e.g., latex + emacs/vim questions) can choose **No** to post on SO.

Can this be implemented? Is this something that can be easily done (with the current framework) or will it require several changes?

Comment: That's pretty awesome an idea.  +1 would +1 again.

Answer (score 11):

This is an interesting idea; what I like about it is that it

- is conditional to the tags selected
- does not cause the user to lose their work
- is a good way to advertise the rest of the network

However one downside is that **I can only really see this being enabled on Stack Overflow**. Given the enormous size of SO and the questions/day pressure we have, that's not a bad thing. But I would *never* push [unix](/questions/tagged/unix) off Server Fault just because a particular question was asked there; the rest of the question's context in the title and body is critical and a tag alone is not enough to decide a destination.

edit: I think the tag wiki summary for specific tags should mention relevant sites:

[image]

Comment: Ok, so we only build it for sites where the number of questions (or the number of migrations) is above a certain number? Therefore we know it has a valid reason to exist (c'mon, sites with over 500,000 questions are almost assuredly going to have plenty of candidates for migration to other sites) and we know that it won't trigger before then. Granted, it's one more branching point, but ...