# Auto suggest wordpress.stackexchange.com when wordpress tag selected

Tags: feature-request, discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [This question may belong to <Another site>, consider migrating - feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12570/this-question-may-belong-to-another-site-consider-migrating-feature-request)

I saw several questions in the past several days that related to wordpress and more appropriate to be asked on wordpress.SE. The latest one is this [How can I add my own contact form in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089184/how-can-i-add-my-own-contact-form-in-wordpress)

Most of the time, this kind of questions is came from newcomers who doesn't even know that there is Wordpress.SE exist. I would like to suggest to add some sort of auto suggest, just like `Questions with similar titles` that pop up just below title, when asking question.

Comment: The auto-suggest dialog should point out that [35% of questions tagged `wordpress` on Stack Overflow go unanswered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress?sort=unanswered&pagesize=50).