# Make suggested off-topic sites dependent on tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, off-topic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrate shortlist based on tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags)
>   [Tag-dependent data-driven off-topic migration suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138440/tag-dependent-data-driven-off-topic-migration-suggestions)

The list of sites suggested via `close` | `off topic` is limited (for good reason), but does not always contain the appropriate SE site for the question. I think that e.g. if a question is tagged [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) it should show SF, SU, and U+L, but not necessarily Sharepoint.SE unless other tags implied it.

Comment: Interesting; knowledgable (experienced) users could then edit the tags to adjust the migration candidates suggested. I wonder if that will fall foul of the same (good) reasons against letting you specify a migration target in other ways.

Comment: Yannis will howl, this would put Programmers back on the migration list :-).

Comment: SO has proven over and over that it doesn't understand the scope of Programmers, SF or sometimes even SU.  However, this is still a cool idea for the other, newer, more-specific sites...