# Help to find the best site for a question

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [This question may belong to <Another site>, consider migrating - feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12570/this-question-may-belong-to-another-site-consider-migrating-feature-request)

I thought this had the potential to be a useful idea.

### Background

One of the issues I've seen is that it's sometimes difficult to determine the best place to as a question on SE.

To relieve posters and mods of some of this hassle, I thought it might be interesting to use tag collections to attempt to solve this.

### Idea

When adding tags, if the user adds a tag that it much more popular on another site, recommend that the other site might be a better place to get the question answered.

For example, I recently couldn't decide if a Crystal Reports-related question (*I know, please pity me*) belonged on SuperUser or on StackOverflow itself. A quick tag comparison showed me that 10 questions were tagged on SU vs. 3500+ on StackOverflow, which helped me solve my problem.

If there was a way for SE sites to intelligently distinguish tag popularity at the time of question writing, it might help remove that question from the process.

### Potential Drawbacks

Of course, care would have to be taken to ensure that a "tipping point" doesn't exist where a certain type of tag then will always be funneled to a certain type. I think this could be mitigated in the way the suggestion is presented (i.e. limiting how forceful the suggestion is in tone).

Just a thought I wanted to pass along,

Comment: great minds think alike. This must not have jumped out at me on potentially related questions due to its phrasing. My question does indeed appear to be a duplicate. I've flagged my own question as a duplicate; hopefully that will help get the go-ahead to close it.

Comment: Indeed, I think it's a very cool idea.  I understand it's tough to seek out of the possible duplicate phrasings sometimes =D

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of questions tagged [site-rec](/questions/tagged/site-rec) on this site. This tag essentially serves the purpose you're trying to accomplish.

Addressing your request directly, the tags on a question are less significant that the content in a question. Your question was about [crystal-reports](/questions/tagged/crystal-reports), but you should decide where to ask it based on what aspect of Crystal Reports your question is about.

For example, your question [Shared Sub-report variable displays last record's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616808/shared-sub-report-variable-displays-last-records-value) is specifically about code that you're using. It is a good fit for Stack Overflow. It would be impossible to determine this looking only at the tags.

You used Super User as an example. If your next Crystal Reports question has something to do with

> - computer hardware
> - computer software
> - personal and home computer networking

then [it's a good fit for Super User](https://superuser.com/faq#questions).

Comment: "overkill" how? "too many bad recommendations" how? Please provide some information/reasoning to go along with your opinion so that I can better understand it.

I think assuming that something will lead to bad recommendations isn't taking into account that I doubt the excellent devs building the site would implement it unless it didn't give awful recommendations. We're talking about matching tags and then comparing the counts for each site. While not the easiest thing, I'm sure it could be pulled off.

Thanks for the "site-rec" tag suggestion; I hadn't seen it as I don't hang around meta much.

Comment: Sorry, those were some initial thoughts. I've refined my position slightly after some more thought.